# required: play.api.mvc.Request[?] => play.api.mvc.Result

Tags: scala, playframework

I am migrating to Play 2.6 and have the following API wrapper functions that used to work:

```
trait API {
    self: Controller =>

    def api(businessLogic: Request[AnyContent] => Any): Action[AnyContent] = apiWithBody(parse.anyContent)(businessLogic)

    def apiWithBody[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(businessLogic: Request[A] => Any): Action[A] = Action(bodyParser) {
        implicit request =>
        {
            val apiResult = businessLogic(request)
            val start = new java.util.Date().getTime
            val actionDuration = (new java.util.Date().getTime - start)
            val response = resultFrom(apiResult, request, actionDuration)    // Returns a Result
            response
        }
    }
}
```

Called by Controller functions like:

```
object Accounts extends Controller with API {

    def all = superUser {
        implicit principal =>
            api {
                request =>
                    models.Account.all
            }
    }
}
```

Where superUser is the principal (user) type "admin".

And get the following compiler error:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Request[?] => play.api.mvc.Result
[error]             api {
[error]                 ^
```

I'm building with sbt 1.1.5 and Scala 2.11.8.

I am guessing the [?] means the compiler doesn't know what type is required but I don't understand what is wrong. I have searched for this issue but not found the specific answer for this problem.

In addition I'm getting an error:

```
[error]  could not find implicit value for parameter parser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[Any]
[error]     def all = superUser {
[error]                         ^
```

that I posted as a separate issue (see [could not find implicit value for parameter parser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[Any]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563383/could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-parser-play-api-mvc-bodyparserany])) but might be relevant here?

```
def superUser[A](f: => Principal => Request[A] => Result)(implicit parser: BodyParser[A]): SecureAction[A] = {
    _superUser {
        user =>
            implicit val principal = data.Principal(user)
            Action(parser)(request => f(principal)(request))
    }
}

private def _superUser[A](action: String => Action[A]) = {
    play.api.mvc.Security.Authenticated(getSuperUser, onUnauthorized)(action)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a starting point, if `all` is a controller function then it should create an [Action](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActions#Actions,-Controllers-and-Results), which - if you are using the Scala API - is a function of type `play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result`. Your first error is telling you that `all` is returning an `Action[AnyContent]` whereas it should be returning an Action function `Request => Result`.

Comment: @Nio I agree, but what changes to the code are you suggesting? Change `Action[AnyContent]` to `Request[AnyContent]`? Tried that but still an error. It's the `Request[?]` that's puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm little bit confused here about the architecture as:

1. Where is the API call? Is it within the model? Are you calling outside the current Play app? Why don't you use the `Future` API for it? Because then you can `recover` it. Which then help you with logging and error handling.
2. The `all` method get the request, and then it does not return an HTTP response. Why don't you pass on what you need from the request (e.g., the `Cookie`).
3. I think the answer to your question is to use your action composition with action. Something like:

   ```
   def myMethod(queryParam: String) = myDefinedAction compose Action { ??? } 

   //In case you want to use the Future API, then you need to be async
   def myMethod(queryParam: String) = (myDefinedAction compose Action).async {
     implicit request => 
        apiCall.map{
          case _ => Ok("good request") 
        }.recover{case _ => BadRequest} 

   }
   ```

Comment: API call is from the controller function `all`. It dispatches to models `def all(implicit principal: Principal) = async {...}` which returns a response after retrieving database results (in this case all accounts packaged up as JSON). The controller `api` call _is_ invoking `Action[A]` which is essentially a `Request[A] => Result` function. So why the error? This used to work! Again, it is the `Request[?]` error that is puzzling me. Is it simply that the compiler does not know the type (ie `AnyContent`) that is the problem here?