# could not find implicit value for parameter parser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[Any]

Tags: scala, playframework

I am migrating to Play 2.6 and have the following Controller function that used to work:

```
object Accounts extends Controller with API {

    def all = superUser {
        implicit principal =>
            api {
                request =>
                    models.Account.all
            }
    }
}
```

and get this error:

```
[error]  could not find implicit value for parameter parser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[Any]
[error]     def all = superUser {
[error]                         ^
```

where:

```
def superUser[A](f: => Principal => Request[A] => Result)(implicit parser: BodyParser[A]): SecureAction[A] = {
    _superUser {
        user =>
            implicit val principal = data.Principal(user)
            Action(parser)(request => f(principal)(request))
    }
}

private def _superUser[A](action: String => Action[A]) = {
    play.api.mvc.Security.Authenticated(getSuperUser, onUnauthorized)(action)
}
```

Please see the related question [required: play.api.mvc.Request[?] => play.api.mvc.Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528872/required-play-api-mvc-request-play-api-mvc-result) for more information on what the `api` wrapper function is.

The question is why is the implicit parameter parser not in scope? Again, this used to work.

Answer (score 0):

`superUser` expects a body parser instance of `A`. `A` in this case is model that you are returning.

Lets say that `models.Account.all` returns `List[Account]`. Now provide json body parser for the `Account` class. Now this body parser requires json reads of Account `Reads[Account]`

```
object Accounts extends Controller with API {

    def all = superUser { implicit principal =>
       api(request => models.Account.all)
    } (parse.json[Account])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to extended AbstractController, BaseController, or InjectedController instead of Controller (it is deprecated).

Play 2.6 doesn't have BodyParsers as implicts on its controllers, but you can access to default parsers through a controller variable *parse*.

If you need a BodyParser for any T, you need to provide access to it.

What version were you using previous to 2.6?

Comment: This is useful, but follow up questions belong in the comments section, not as answers.

Comment: @ SebastianCelestino: I previously was using Play 2.0.2. I'm not sure I understand what you are saying about the `BodyParser` controller variable `parse` I but will investigate that as well as the depricated Controller issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import com.google.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class Accounts @Inject() (components: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(components) with API {

    def all = superUser { implicit principal =>
       api(request => models.Account.all)
    } (parse.anyContent)
}
```

and now it compiles without the error. I have not tested it yet since I have another error to fix (see the above link).

`Accounts` used to be an `object` but now it is a `Singleton class`. Does anyone have a comment about this implementation working?